# How can I highlight text in Microsoft Powerpoint?

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint

I have downloaded a presentation from Google Slides as .pptx and need to edit it.

The slide contains highlighted text which displays correctly but I need to change the highlight colour and cannot find the option to change this in Powerpoint.

Except for a workaround editing the text highlight colors on Google Slides and re-downloading it is there a way to do this directly in PowerPoint?

I run PowerPoint for Mac from Office365, version 15.12.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft PowerPoint 2013, one way is to copy the text you want to highlight to Microsoft Word, highlight in Microsoft Word and copy it back to Microsoft PowerPoint:

[image]

(video author: [Craig Hadden](https://remotepossibilities.wordpress.com/))

---

Highlighting text in PowerPoint for Office 365 and PowerPoint 2019 ([official documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/highlight-your-text-28623777-d955-4fcf-bbc5-a50051552219#OfficeVersion=Web)) is more convenient as there is a direct option for it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint 2013 and earlier do not support text highlighting yet, although apparently it can render it.  Not sure what version that Mac one maps too, but I don't think it's supported.

Maybe try creating the highlighting in MS Word and pasting into PPT.